# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am still on Ubuntu 18.04

After uninstalling & installing node and npm I get this in my terminal when booting

> /home/alex/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/bootstrap.js:21
> import('../lib/init.js'); ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
> at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
> at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
> at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> at Object. (/home/alex/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js:28:3)

I want to install clean version of npm & node

Thank you